# Missing image in Intent when receiving simple data from other apps on Android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-intent

I have programmed my app so that it can receive simple data from other apps, as described in https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/receive. The goal is that when I want to share content from Instagram, Chrome or wherever, my app appears in the list below:

[image]

I have added the following lines to the AndroidManifest.xml, associated to MyActivity, which is where I manage the corresponding Intent with the content shared from other apps:

```
<activity android:name=".ui.MyActivity" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Then, I receive and handle the Intent in MyActivity:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    ...
    when {
        intent?.action == Intent.ACTION_SEND -> {
            if ("text/plain" == intent.type) {
                handleSendText(intent) // Handle text being sent
            } else if (intent.type?.startsWith("image/") == true) {
                handleSendImage(intent) // Handle single image being sent
            }
        }
        intent?.action == Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE
                && intent.type?.startsWith("image/") == true -> {
                handleSendMultipleImages(intent) // Handle multiple images being sent
        }
        else -> {
            // Handle other intents, such as being started from the home screen
        }
    }
    ...
}

private fun handleSendText(intent: Intent) {
    intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT)?.let {
        // Update UI to reflect text being shared
        ...
    }
}

private fun handleSendImage(intent: Intent) {
    (intent.getParcelableExtra<Parcelable>(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM) as? Uri)?.let {
        // Update UI to reflect image being shared
        ...
    }
}

private fun handleSendMultipleImages(intent: Intent) {
    intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra<Parcelable>(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM)?.let {
        // Update UI to reflect multiple images being shared
        ...
    }
}
```

This works except that I can't locate the image information in any of the examples I've tried. That is, I never get anything in `intent.getParcelableExtra<Parcelable>(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM)`. I have read that these Intents do not always content the information of the image but I have tried, for example, to share https://es.ign.com/the-legend-of-zelda-breath-of-the-wild-2/190693/review/analisis-de-the-legend-of-zelda-tears-of-the-kingdom-la-culminacion-de-breath-of-the-wild to WhatsApp and there I do see that image:

[image]

But if I share that same link to my app, as I say, the Intent doesn't seem to contain any image.

Any ideas?

Comment: That image isn't included in the intent, that is Whatsapp providing a preview of the website by reading the metadata from the webpage themselves.